# How do I break a string into an array based on a token?

Tags: string, swift

**Background**

For example, suppose I have:

```
let tgt     = "Europa"
let token   = "ro"
let a       = split_on( tgt, token )    // how to implement this?
let exp_res = [ "Eu", "ro", "pa" ]
```

I considered using `String.componentsSeparatedByString` but the split positions are lost (i.e. we do not know if the `token` appeared at the beginning, end, or if it occurred multiple times in a row.

**Edit: Additional Examples**

```
split_on( "roroEuropa", "ro" ) // [ "ro", "ro", "Eu", "ro", "pa" ]
split_on( "rorEuropa",  "ro" ) // [ "ro", "rEu", "ro", "pa" ]
split_on( "Euroroparo", "ro" ) // [ "Eu", "ro", "ro", "pa", "ro" ]
```

Comment: So what output would you expect if the token appears at the beginning, end, or if it occurs multiple times in a row ? Some more examples would be helpful.

Comment: @MartinR I would expect multiple "ro"s, even repeated in the array - at beginning, end, or wherever they show up.  I don't want to lose any instances - they should show up in the output.  The tokens only serve as our splitting point(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be a possible solution. You could write it in a single line,
but I have split it into separate statements to demonstrate how it works:

```
let tgt     = "roEuroroparo"
let token   = "ro"

// Split into an array of strings:
let t1 = tgt.componentsSeparatedByString(token)
println(t1)                   // [, Eu, , pa, ]

// Convert each string to an array:
let t2 = map(t1) { [$0] }
println(t2)                   // [[], [Eu], [], [pa], []]

// Interpose the token:
let t3 = [token].join(t2)
println(t3)                   // [, ro, Eu, ro, , ro, pa, ro, ]

// Remove empty strings:
let result = filter(t3) { countElements($0) > 0 }
println(result)               // [ro, Eu, ro, ro, pa, ro]
```